# Jquery class switching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons inside a list and I want to be able to switch a class between them on click.

I'm a beginner on Jquery and wrote some lines but it doesn't seem to work, even though everything is correctly linked according to Chrome's console.

Here's the html :

```
<ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
</ul>
```

and here's the corresponding Jquery :

```
$('.tab a').click(function) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
     $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
     target = $(this).attr('href');
     $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
     $(target).fadeIn(600);
});
```

Thanks in advance !

So it seems to be working now, partially, it doesn't work in my full HTML page but it does when using only the `<ul>`, so i'll redo it from the beginning and find where it goes wrong.

Thanks a lot for all of your answers !

Comment: Did you check the answer? Please accept it if it's correct (click on the V on the left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You had a syntax error - it should be `$('.tab a').click(function() {`
2. If you want to use the event object (`e.preventDefault()` in your code) you should add it to the function declaration - `function(e) {`, otherwise the `e` variable is not defined.

Here is the fix to your code:

```js
$('.tab a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
  target = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
  $(target).fadeIn(600);
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: blue;
}
.active a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a second!

Comment: @AutumnLeonard you will get the next one ;) (Thanks for the vote-up, I guess)

Comment: Not sure if this is a question for you or the OP but should `target` be global here or was this intentional?

Comment: @CarlEdwards, probably  a question to the OP, I don't think it's intentionally. You can also avoid this variable completely.

Comment: Agreed. It looks `this` would still suffice as a substitute in the next two lines.